# Как исправить регулярное выражение, чтобы заработало?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, autoit

Вот код. Нужно спарсить содержимое тега **ul**. Пример текста:

```
 <h2 class="cut-top">Рекомендації</h2>
 <ul>
    <li>Костенко Евгения<br>HR-менеджер, Sicore, 099-121-15-10</li>
 </ul>
 <hr>
```

`(?:<ul>)(\n.*\n)(?:<\/ul>)` - это не работает почему-то

Comment: как именно вы применяете регулярное выражение? какой язык/утилиту используете?

Comment: `#include <Array.au3>     
$linkRead = BinaryToString(InetRead("https://www.work.ua/ua/resumes/3135656/", 17), 4)     
$re = '/(?:<ul>)(.*)(?:<\/ul>)/s';
$recomendationTxt = StringRegExp($linkRead, $re, 3)
_ArrayDisplay($recomendationTxt)` кусок кода, который не работает. Язык Autoit.

Comment: исправьте ваш вопрос

Comment: уже нашел решение, благодаря вашей подсказке;-)

Comment: исправьте вопрос. добавьте ответ.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman почему вы хотите создать новую метку [tag:autoit]?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov это-то вопрос не про просто регулярное выражение, а регулярное выражение в Autoit. Для проверки ответа надо использовать Autoit.

Comment: Неужели вы парсите HTML с помощью регулярных выражений?

Comment: А вариант лучше?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
'(?s)(?:Рекомендації<\/h2>)(?:\s*<ul>\s*<li>)(.*)(?:<\/li>\s*<\/ul>\s*<hr>)' ура заработало.
```

**Дело было в пробельных символах.**

Comment: у вас ответ не совпадает с вопросом

Comment: Что не совпадает?

Comment: в вопросе нет `<hr>`. это значит, что те кто пробовал ответить не имели полной информации.